# How to implement a custom serialization only for serde_json?

Tags: json, rust, serde

I want to be able to serialize a `Vec<u8>` as a base64-encoded string for JSON (and other UTF-8-based formats) while keeping an array of bytes for binary serialization formats.

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct MyStruct {
    binary_data: Vec<u8>,
}
```

By default, serde_json will serialize the `binary_data` field as an array of numbers. Instead, I want to have it serialized as a string encoded with base64. Yet, I want to keep bincode (or any other binary format) using raw bytes and avoid base64 conversion.

The only solution I came up with is to create a copy of a data structure specifically for the serializer, but that is really annoying and inefficient when you have nested structures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on Derde's documentation, you can't provide a special implementation of the `Serialize` trait for a concrete serializer for the same structure.

You can create a newtype struct and then provide a custom `serde::{Des,S}erialize` implementation for `StringableMyStruct` to support `String`s in fields:

```
pub struct StringableMyStruct(MyStruct);
```

Comment: While it did not solve my problem, it seems to be the only answer I can get. Thank you for confirming my suspicion.