# Can I change how a Rust data structure serializes based on the target serialization format?

Tags: rust, serde

When implementing a custom Rust serde `Serialize` implementation, is there any way to make the serialization depend on the capabilities of the format to which the structure is being serialized?

My specific use case is that I have a structure with file checksums, represented in memory as `u8` arrays. When serializing to a text format like JSON, TOML, or YAML, I would like to serialize (and deserialize) them as hex-encoded strings.  But when serializing to a binary format such as bincode or msgpack, I would like to serialize the `u8` bytes directly.

Is this possible with `Serialize`, or do I need separate structures for text-encoded and binary-encoded digests and have client code convert types based on how they're serializing the structure?

I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60008192/how-to-implement-a-custom-serialization-only-for-serde-json), but mine is slightly different (but may have the same ultimate answer): that question is concerned with overriding the derived serialize implementation for a specific serializer, and mine is concerned with serializer-specific behavior in a custom `Serialize` implementation.

Comment: Just to check, will this method - https://docs.rs/serde/latest/serde/trait.Serializer.html#method.is_human_readable - make the difference you expect?

Comment: @Cerberus That looks like exactly what I am looking for. Turn it into an answer and I will mark it as accepted :).